# get_header() in backend - but keep JavaScript and CSS files

Tags: javascript, headers, footer, custom-header

I replaced the header and footer in the backend with those from the frontend by the following code:

```
/* add header to backend */
function header_backend() {
  get_header();
}
add_filter('in_admin_header', 'header_backend');

/* add footer to backend */
function footer_backend() {
    get_footer();
}
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'footer_backend');
```

But this obviously deactivated or removed the *.js and *.css files which were loaded by the original backend header/footer.

Is there any way to replace the backend header/footer with those of the frontend and keeping all JS-functionality and CSS styles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

obviously the answer is no. wordpress do not load JS and CSS on the admin side if it is not needed.

In addition your method will probably trigger all kinds of plugins which assume that wp_head and wp_footer are triggered only at the frontend which might create "interesting" side effects.

If you want to customize the admin you will have to actually write specific code for it.

Comment: So there is no simple way to load the fronted header and footer and its navigation menu into the backend AND keep the backend's JS functionality and CSS style in the content section?

Comment: There is no simple way. The admin side of wordpress is not designed to be easily customized with anything more complex then can be done with CSS. You should keep in mind that some functions ignore filters when used on the admin side. You can probably do small changes but the bigger the changes are the more likely you will run into problems at some point.